# Confusing error when updating packages in Julia 0.5.0

Tags: julia, gadfly

When attempting to update the installed packages on my Windows 10 laptop with Julia 0.5.0 installed, the following error appeared with regard to Rmath:

```
C:\Users\CaitlinG>julia -e "Pkg.update()"
INFO: Updating METADATA...
INFO: Updating cache of ColorTypes...
INFO: Updating cache of Gadfly...
INFO: Updating cache of StatsBase...
INFO: Updating cache of DataFrames...
INFO: Updating cache of FixedPointNumbers...
INFO: Updating cache of Colors...
INFO: Updating cache of DataFrames...
INFO: Computing changes...
INFO: Upgrading ColorTypes: v0.2.8 => v0.2.11
INFO: Upgrading Colors: v0.6.8 => v0.6.9
INFO: Upgrading FixedPointNumbers: v0.1.8 => v0.2.1
INFO: Upgrading Gadfly: v0.5.0 => v0.5.1
INFO: Upgrading StatsBase: v0.11.0 => v0.11.1
INFO: Building Rmath
================================[ ERROR: Rmath ]================================


LoadError: ArgumentError: Module BinDeps not found in current path.
Run `Pkg.add("BinDeps")` to install the BinDeps package.
while loading C:\users\caitling\emacs251\.julia\v0.5\Rmath\deps\build.jl, in exp
ression starting on line 1

================================================================================


================================[ BUILD ERRORS ]================================


WARNING: Rmath had build errors.

 - packages with build errors remain installed in C:\users\caitling\emacs251\.ju
lia\v0.5
 - build the package(s) and all dependencies with `Pkg.build("Rmath")`
 - build a single package by running its `deps/build.jl` script

================================================================================
```

I am also confused by the inability of Julia to locate 'Gadfly.jl' despite the fact that it is installed as the above output would indicate.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried doing what it says i.e. `Pkg.add("BinDeps")` ?

Comment: Hi. Yes, Julia stated that there was nothing to be done which would indicate that the package was already installed?

Comment: Did you try `Pkg.build("Rmath")`?

Comment: The same message appeared. Evidently, Julia cannot locate 'BinDeps' on the path. I'm quite confused at this point since I am experiencing difficulty locating BinDeps.jl

Comment: Possibly related to [this issue](https://github.com/JuliaStats/StatsBase.jl/issues/202)?

Comment: Did you get this fixed?  I'm having the same issue.  Failed BinDeps leads to inability to use Atom/Juno.

Comment: Hi. No, unfortunately, I have not. The same error has occurred on both Windows XP (sp3) and Windows 10. I am at a loss of how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be due to the path to your package directory being case sensitive. I had the same problem after specifying a local package directory until I realised, thanks to [this discussion](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/windows-capitalization-of-the-home-environment-variable/200), that I had the wrong capitalisation in the specified path.

I'm pretty sure `C:\\users` should be `C:\\Users` but check the rest of your path which is currently:

`C:\users\caitling\emacs251\.julia\`

you can then check if this is the problem by

```
ENV["JULIA_PKGDIR"] ="C:\\Users\\caitling\\emacs251\\.julia"
Pkg.build("Rmath")
```