# Julia 0.5.0 -- Can't get Atom working due to HTTPParser due to BinDeps

Tags: julia, atom-editor

Using Win7 x64

Wiped out `c:\users\myname\.julia` as well as anything in `AppData`, reinstalled fresh binaries of julia-0.5.0 and Atom-1.12.9, and `uber-juno`.

When starting first run of Julia, the console tells me to run `Pkg.build("HttpParser")`, which fails due to not finding `BinDeps` in the current path, and a red error box tells me to run `Pkg.update()`.  Running update tells me everything is fine.  Trying to add `BinDeps` directly appears to work, but then trying to `use` it fails.

There are other links to this type of problem, eventually suggesting a failed install script for `BinDeps`. I did not have this problem with 0.4.5.

Below snapshot shows trying to add `BinDeps` manually on a clean `.julia` directory.

```
julia> Pkg.add("BinDeps")
INFO: Initializing package repository c:\users\mschwager\.julia\v0.5
INFO: Cloning METADATA from https://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl
INFO: Cloning cache of BinDeps from     https://github.com/JuliaLang/BinDeps.jl.git
INFO: Cloning cache of Compat from     https://github.com/JuliaLang/Compat.jl.git
INFO: Cloning cache of SHA from https://github.com/staticfloat/SHA.jl.git
INFO: Cloning cache of URIParser from     https://github.com/JuliaWeb/URIParser.jl.git
INFO: Installing BinDeps v0.4.5
INFO: Installing Compat v0.10.0
INFO: Installing SHA v0.3.0
INFO: Installing URIParser v0.1.6
INFO: Package database updated

julia> using BinDeps
ERROR: ArgumentError: Module BinDeps not found in current path.
Run `Pkg.add("BinDeps")` to install the BinDeps package.
 in require(::Symbol) at .\loading.jl:365
```

- Where does Julia look for `BinDeps`?  There is definitely such a subdirectory within `.julia/v0.5` folder
- Is there a workaround/fix?
- Can I build `HttpParser` without `BinDeps`?
- Will I run into other packages that need `BinDeps`?

Yes I've seen several of the forum discussions and other SO posts, such as [Julia: Problems with Adding Packages (BinDeps)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650988/julia-problems-with-adding-packages-bindeps) and [Confusing error when updating packages in Julia 0.5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40003303/confusing-error-when-updating-packages-in-julia-0-5-0) and https://github.com/JuliaStats/StatsBase.jl/issues/202., but no fix yet after trying to build the package at the lowest level of the failure.

Thanks

Comment: what happens if you include("~/.julia/v0.5/BinDeps/src/BinDeps.jl")?

Comment: Thanks, just tried this, it leads to not finding `Module Compat`  Turns out, none of the packages in the `Pkg.installed()` list work, so I think it's about where Julia is looking for Modules.  How do I verify the julia path?

Comment: Julia looks for packages in the paths stored in the variable `LOAD_PATH`. The Julia binary is stored in `JULIA_HOME`. So just type `LOAD_PATH` and `JULIA_HOME` in the REPL and verify those directories are at the correct places.

Comment: This is what I get: `julia> LOAD_PATH
2-element Array{String,1}:
 "C:\\Program Files\\Julia-0.5.0\\local\\share\\julia\\site\\v0.5"
 "C:\\Program Files\\Julia-0.5.0\\share\\julia\\site\\v0.5"` but the local subdirectory doesn't exist, and anyway the share\julia\site location is empty,.  Where is LOAD_PATH defined?  All my modules are in c:\users\myname\.julia\v0.5.  I think I can maybe do something like `@everywhere push!(LOAD_PATH,"/path/to/my/code")`

Comment: I've added the path to the modules, but nothing loads up.  I've asked in https://discourse.julialang.org

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the capitalization in my `HOME` environment variable.  Now the modules load up as per https://discourse.julialang.org/t/windows-capitalization-of-the-home-environment-variable/200